# React pass data attribute to DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, attributes, jsx

I'm extending a component and want to add extra attributes to it. To add a new class attribute I'm using:

```
extraProps.className = 'some-value';
```

or an ID...

```
extraProps.ID = 'some-value';
```

but how can I add a data attribute? e.g. `data-my-attribute`

I tried camelCase convention:

```
extraProps.dataMyAttribute = 'some-value';
```

...but it doesn't add dashes in the outputted HTML. It outputs `dataMyAttribute='some-value'`

Full code:

```
function addMyProp( extraProps, props ) {

    extraProps.dataSomeAttribute = 'something' // it doesn't add the data- prefix

    return extraProps;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `setAttribute`?

Comment: Yes but getting `Syntax error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression` this might be more of a syntax issue. I want to add it to extraProps which is an object

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. You should technically be able to place whatever you want into the html element when using `setAttribute`. Just to be 100% sure though, both the 1st (attribute name) and 2nd 
 (attribute value) argument are strings.

Comment: what about `extraProps['data-my-attribute'] = 'some-value';` ?

Comment: @Andrew I added the full code

Comment: how do you use that function addMyProp?

Comment: @HaiAlaluf actually extraProps['data-my-attribute'] seems to work. I must have been using it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data attributes react [doesn't require camel case](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html).

Have you tried `extraProps['data-my-attribute'] = 'something'` ?

Answer (score 0):

**From the official documentation**:
*In React, all DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers) should be camelCased. For example, the HTML attribute `tabindex` corresponds to the attribute `tabIndex` in React. The exception is `aria-*` and `data-*` attributes, which should be lowercased. For example, you can keep `aria-label` as `aria-label.*`

So you should use attribute naming for a custom property like this:

```
extraProps['data-my-attribute'] = 'something';
```